# Which method is called after an intent starts an Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, oncreate

I know that when an activity is first created its onCreate() method comes into play.

Assume that there's a main activity which starts another activity (secondActivity.java) through an intent and then that second activity starts the main activity again through an intent. My question is that whether onRestart() method is called of the main activity after receiving the intent or is onCreate() method called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just try it? just override the methods, call the super.... and the log the methodname

Comment: I did and the onCreate method was being called and I was confused as it shouldn't be, because onCreate is called just once throughout the lifecycle.

Comment: But CommonsWare's answer made everything clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is that whether onRestart() method is called of the main activity after receiving the intent or is onCreate() method called?

That depends on whether a new instance of the main activity will be created.

By default, one will. In that case, the new instance of the main activity will be called with `onCreate()`. The *original* instance of the main activity is left alone.

However, via `Intent` flags (e.g., `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`) or manifest settings, you could arrange to have the original instance of the main activity brought back to the foreground. In that case, the original instance will be called with `onNewIntent()` (to provide you with the `Intent` used with `startActivity()` that brought the activity back to the foreground). It should also be called with `onRestart()`, `onStart()`, and `onResume()` as part of coming back to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks! So, is it better if I get my original instance of main to the foreground or is it ok if I just let another instance of main be created?

Comment: @RohanBhatia: That is up to you. Reusing the activity saves memory. But, to some extent, it depends on how you are setting up your navigation. If you create a new instance, your activity sequence is M -> S -> M2 (M=main, S=second, M2=2nd instance of main). And so when the user presses BACK from M2, they go to S, and when they press BACK from S, they go to M. If you reorder the stack and reuse M, when the user presses BACK from M they go to S, and when they press BACK from S, they exit your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an image from the Android life cycle from the documentation:

[image: Android life cycle]

When you launch a second activity `onPause()`, etc will be called on the first Activity then `onCreate()` and so on will be called on the second activity. As you can see in the diagram above when you press back `onRestart()` should be called on the first activity.

Comment: I added some more details in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a new intent the `onCreate()` method is called.

Comment: Are you sure, because the android developer site says -The entire lifetime of an activity happens between the first call to onCreate(Bundle) through to a single final call to onDestroy().